# A value used in the formula is of wrong data type when calling a UDF

Tags: function, vba, excel, syntax-error

I've been trying hard to figure out what went wrong here. I have two cols which contain string values. I use the third col to call a UDF in the worksheet, but end up getting #Value with error - "A value used in the formula is of wrong data type".

Eg:

```
 Col I   Col J
 File1    Y
 File1    N
 File2    Y
 File3    N
```

I tried debugging it, and the input values were passed fine into the function variables.
My knowledge in VBA is limited, hoping you guys can help me out in resolving this issue.

**Function called in worksheet:**

```
=FileCheck(I3,I3:J38)
```

**Code:**

```
Public Function FileCheck(V As Range, Q As Range) As String
    Dim vtest As Variant
    Dim i, j, stat As Integer

    stat = 0

    vtest = Q

    For i = 1 To UBound(vtest)
        If V = vtest(i, 1) And vtest(i, 2) = "N" Then

            For j = 1 To UBound(vtest)
                If V = vtest(j, 1) And vtest(j, 2) = "Y" Then

                    FileCheck = "Y"
                    stat = 1
                End If
            Next
            If stat = 0 Then
                FileCheck = "N"
                End
            Else: End
            End If


        ElseIf V = vtest(i, 1) And vtest(i, 2) = "Y" Then
            FileCheck = "Y"
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Can you please step through your code and provide the line that causes the error?

Comment: FYI: on this line `Dim i, j, stat As Integer`, you are only defining `stat` as an integer. `i` and `j` will be defined as variant as there is no AS statement before the comma separating them

Comment: Thanks for this, I had taken this as easy route of declaring variables without realising this would invariably declare them as Variants.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting that error because you are using `End`.

When you want to turn your computer off, do you click on `Start Menu ~~> Shut down` or do you pull the power cable out directly? **:-)**

Using `End` is very similar to pulling the cable. Don't use `End`. Exit the function gracefully. The `End` statement is basically a way of making your program crash, but without showing any error messages.

Try this. Replace these lines

```
If stat = 0 Then
    FileCheck = "N"
    End
Else: End
End If
```

with

```
If stat = 0 Then FileCheck = "N"
Exit Function
```

**EDIT**

BTW, are you trying to find the corresponding value of `Col I` in `Col J`? If yes, then you do not need a UDF for this. You can use `Vlookup()`

Use this formula `=VLOOKUP(I3,I3:J38,2,0)` instead of `=FileCheck(I3,I3:J38)`

Comment: Thanks for this. I've now used Exit function and it returns value prefectly. I'm not just trying to do a vlookup, I'm intending to  loop through the data, to change value N to Y, if any values of Col I have the same filenames with values Y and N.

Answer (score 1):

I think your first input type should be a string not a range:

```
V as string
```

Additional you need to use `exit function` when you want to end the function however I'm not sure if you want to end the function, end the if statement or the for loops?

Comment: I've replaced the end statment with Exit for (also tested with exit function), the result is returned as expected. Thanks.